# Identify a fantasy book about a girl who finds a word of power

Tags: story-identification, books

This book was set in a city that had angel/avian guards. The heroine discovered a word of power, solved some puzzle in a garden, and encountered a demon/entity trapped underneath a temple or something?

I read this about a decade ago from my high school library and it was an older book even then. I think it was written by a female author.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192841/fantasy-novel-where-magic-is-granted-by-knowledge-of-words-of-power

Comment: This could possibly be Marion Zimmer Bradley's *The Fall of Atlantis* (originally published in two volumes as *Web if Light / Web of Darkness*). But it has been so long sinced I read the book that I can't remember if it fits all the details. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/478846.The_Fall_of_Atlantis

Comment: @Valorum That's what I thought at first, but the angel-guarded city is a detail that doesn't match.